# Removing additional, extra periods (dots) from tokens while indexing in solr

Tags: solr

I want to remove extra periods between tokens when solr indexes documents.
I can always do this with custom code before indexing to solr. But is there a tokenizer or analyzer or configuration which will strip off unnecessary periods(dots)?
Example: **This repair shop is very good... I would recommend it to anyone who wants to repair their bikes...Please give it a try.....**

I have gone through multiple tokenizers and analyzers. None of them seem to work for this.
I am currently using **solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory** and **solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory** along with few other filters.
Because of the way I am using WordDelimiterFilterFactory, solr  is generating
good, good..., bikes..., bikes, bikesplease, try, try.....

I dont want solr to generate the tokens with **...** at the end.
Any ideas on how to do it without writing custom code?.........

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried solr.StandardTokenizerFactory ?

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.StandardTokenizerFactory

I tried this tokenizer and seems to work as you expected.

Comment: Hi ymonad, the documentation says "There aren't any filters that use StandardTokenizer's types." I need the subsequent filters to understand these tokens. Any ideas on that?

Comment: More precisely, can this standardtokenizer be attached to subsequent sophisticated filters like worddelimiterfilter and snowballfilter etc.?

Comment: Thank you. I tried this and the other filters can recognize these tokens. I am searching if there are any downsides to this over whitespace tokenizer